# how to export listbox to notepad in vb?

Tags: vb.net

i have contains listbox. how to export listbox to notepad in vb? Please advise me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Notepad typically reads and writes plain old `.txt` files.  These can be written with a standard [StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-5.0).  Just iterate over your ListBox and write each item to your file:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim txtFile As String = "C:\Users\mikes\Documents\Test.txt"
    Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter(txtFile, False)
        For Each item As String In ListBox1.Items
            sw.WriteLine(item)
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

If you don't want to hard-code a filename, then use a [SaveFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=net-5.0) to get a filename from the user.

Comment: Or just `IO.File.WriteAllLines(txtFile, ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String))`. OP might also want to call `Process.Start(txtFile)` afterward if they actually want to display the text in Notepad.